# Join question when you have all keyword in the row

Tags: sql

I am unable to figure out a small problem if anyone can help me out here.

I have to join two tables where one table has a row with a Keyword `All` in it .

If the `All` keyword is there then it should create one row for all the varieties of food.

Datatable 1:

| resturant | Food |
| --- | --- |
| resturant1 | pancake |
| resturant2 | egg |
| resturant3 | All |

Datatable 2

| Column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | pancake |
| B | egg |

Expected output

| resturant | Food | Column 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| resturant1 | pancake | A |
| resturant2 | egg | B |
| resturant3 | pancake | A |
| resturant3 | egg | B |

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can join using a non-trivial predicate. For example:

```
select
  a.restaurant,
  b.column2 as food,
  b.column1
from datatable1 a
join datatable2 b on b.column2 = a.food or a.food = 'All'
```